# Identificar elemento visible

Tags: javascript, angular

Mi problema es que necesito una propiedad o algo para poder saber si un elemento (div) esta visible en la ventana del scroll y de igual manero ni esta escondido

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Siendo 'testdiv' el elemento que quieres consultar puedes comprobar su visibilidad desde javascript usando:

```
document.getElementById('testdiv').style.visibility.
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que tu div tenga un `id` o un `class` y haz esta comprobación (necesitas javascript)

```
<div id="contenedor"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($("div#contenedor").css('display') == 'none' || 
        $("div#contenedor").css("visibility") == "hidden"){
        // El div no se muestra en pantalla
    } else {
        // El div se muestra en pantalla
    }
</script>
```

Con `class` sería lo mismo pero con un punto  - `div.contenedor`